# Get linear index for multidimensional access

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

I'm trying to implement a multidimensional std::array, which hold a contigous array of memory of size Dim-n-1 * Dim-n-2 * ... * Dim-1. For that, i use private inheritance from std::array :

```
constexpr std::size_t factorise(std::size_t value)
{
    return value;
}

template<typename... Ts>
constexpr std::size_t factorise(std::size_t value, Ts... values)
{
    return value * factorise(values...);
}

template<typename T, std::size_t... Dims>
class multi_array : std::array<T, factorise(Dims...)>
{
    // using directive and some stuff here ...

    template<typename... Indexes>
    reference operator() (Indexes... indexes)
    {
        return base_type::operator[] (linearise(std::make_integer_sequence<Dims...>(), indexes...)); // Not legal, just to explain the need.
    }
 }
```

For instance, `multi_array<5, 2, 8, 12> arr; arr(2, 1, 4, 3) = 12;` will access to the linear index `idx = 2*(5*2*8) + 1*(2*8) + 4*(8) + 3`.

I suppose that i've to use std::integer_sequence, passing an integer sequence to the linearise function and the list of the indexes, but i don't know how to do it. What i want is something like :

```
template<template... Dims, std::size_t... Indexes>
auto linearise(std::integer_sequence<int, Dims...> dims, Indexes... indexes)
{
    return (index * multiply_but_last(dims)) + ...;
}
```

With multiply_but_last multiplying all remaining dimension but the last (i see how to implement with a constexpr variadic template function such as for factorise, but i don't understand if it is possible with std::integer_sequence).

I'm a novice in variadic template manipulation and std::integer_sequence and I think that I'm missing something. Is it possible to get the linear index computation without overhead (i.e. like if the operation has been hand-writtent) ?

Thanks you very much for your help.

Comment: Where you wrote `factorise` I would have expected `product`: to factorize (or just factor) means to obtain the factors _from_ the product.

Comment: It's true, thanks !

Comment: to use same `...` for 2 variadic, they should have the same size (you might then use other function just to add "empty" value (`0`)). then `((indexes * factors) + ...)` would be valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following might help:

```
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>

template <std::size_t, typename T> using alwaysT_t = T;

template<typename T, std::size_t ... Dims>
class MultiArray
{
public:
    const T& operator() (alwaysT_t<Dims, std::size_t>... indexes) const
    {
        return values[computeIndex(indexes...)];
    }
    T& operator() (alwaysT_t<Dims, std::size_t>... indexes)
    {
        return values[computeIndex(indexes...)];
    }

private:
    size_t computeIndex(alwaysT_t<Dims, std::size_t>... indexes_args) const
    {
        constexpr std::size_t dimensions[] = {Dims...};
        std::size_t indexes[] = {indexes_args...};

        size_t index = 0;
        size_t mul = 1;

        for (size_t i = 0; i != sizeof...(Dims); ++i) {
            assert(indexes[i] < dimensions[i]);
            index += indexes[i] * mul;
            mul *= dimensions[i];
        }
        assert(index < (Dims * ...));
        return index;
    }

private:
    std::array<T, (Dims * ...)> values;
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82c0caa5eb360ce4)

I replaced your `factorize` by fold expression (C++17).

Comment: Thanks, good point for fold expression.
Between, your computation is incorrect and would lead to have : multi_array<4, 3, 2> m; m(2, 2, 1) === m[2 + 2*4 + 1*4*3] instead of m[2*4*3 + 2*3 + 1] (tell me if i'm wrong).
Is it possible to have :
return ( (indexes * multiply_but_last<Dims>()) + ... ); for the linearise function ?  with multiply_but_last that return the product of each Dim but the last.
Also, i would prefer a free function of possible.
Thanks

Comment: I provide link with some tests which should validate that my indexes computation is coherent. If my order of dimension is not what you want, you may easily fix indexing `dimension[i]` -> `dimension[sizeof...(Dims) - 1- i]`. The method can easily be promoted to free function: template <std::size_t ... Dims> size_t computeIndex(std::index_sequence<Dims...>, alwaysT_t<Dims, std::size_t>... indexes_args).

Comment: Yes it is pretty easy to fix it to get the good indexing. Thank you. A last concern, what is the overhead of this index computation compared to the hard-coded operation (without genericity) ?

Comment: The loop might be unrolled, so potentially no overhead. But, you have to measure and/or check assembly,

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanations :)

Comment: @Jarod42 Would you mind explaining what the purpose of `alwaysT_t` is? That's the only thing I'm somewhat confused about.

Comment: From `Is...` (`[0, 1, 2]`), I want `sizeof...(Is)` parameters of type `T` (so `T t1, T t2, T t3`). To do that, I create an alias that I can expand: `alwaysT_t<std::size_t, T>`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very simple function that converts multi-dimensional index to 1D index.

```cpp
#include <initializer_list>

template<typename ...Args>
inline constexpr size_t IDX(const Args... params) {
  constexpr size_t NDIMS = sizeof...(params) / 2 + 1;
  std::initializer_list<int> args{params...};
  auto ibegin = args.begin();
  auto sbegin = ibegin + NDIMS;
  size_t res = 0;
  for (int dim = 0; dim < NDIMS; ++dim) {
    size_t factor = dim > 0 ? sbegin[dim - 1] : 0;
    res = res * factor + ibegin[dim];
  }
  return res;
}
```

> You may need to add "-Wno-c++11-narrowing" flag to your compiler if you see a warning like `non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'int'`.

Example usage:

2D array

```cpp
int array2D[rows*cols];
// Usually, you need to access the element at (i,j) like this:
int elem = array2D[i * cols + j]; // = array2D[i,j]
// Now, you can do it like this:
int elem = array2D[IDX(i,j,cols)]; // = array2D[i,j]
```

3D array

```cpp
int array3D[rows*cols*depth];
// Usually, you need to access the element at (i,j,k) like this:
int elem = array3D[(i * cols + j) * depth + k]; // = array3D[i,j,k]
// Now, you can do it like this:
int elem = array3D[IDX(i,j,k,cols,depth)]; // = array3D[i,j,k]
```

ND array

```cpp
// shapes = {s1,s2,...,sn}
T arrayND[s1*s2*...*sn]
// indices = {e1,e2,...,en}
T elem = arrayND[IDX(e1,e2,...,en,s2,...,sn)] // = arrayND[e1,e2,...,en]
```

Note that the shape parameters passed to `IDX(...)` begins at the second shape, which is `s2` in this case.

> BTW: This implementation requires C++ 14.