# Computing the linear index of a multi-dimensional array when using the curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP)

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, c++20, crtp

I am writing a multi-dimensional array class in C++ and would like to have static and dynamic memory versions of it. Based on an answer from one of my [previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69503961/is-it-possible-to-create-different-derived-classes-sharing-the-same-methods-that/69504147?noredirect=1#comment122865663_69504147), I used CRTP to define a base class which then has access to the respective data containers (std::array and std::vector) with contiguous memory in the derived classes.

I wish to implement the multi-dimensional subscript operator (e.g. to access the (1, 2) entry of a 4x3 matrix whose 12 entries are stored contiguously in memory) in the base class itself so as to avoid code duplication. Note that I just picked the subscript operator as it is the simplest class method that illustrates what I wish to achieve. I have attempted to adapt the multi-dimensional subscript linearisation solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50652056/get-linear-index-for-multidimensional-access) by @Jarod42 to my case with CRTP. However, I am unsure about how to store the array dimensions in the derived classes in order to infer them in the base class when computing the linearised index. I hope the following code demonstrates my issue clearly (I am compiling with C++20):

```
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <vector>

/** Multi-dimensional Array Base Class with CRTP. */
template <class derived, class T>
class MultiDimArray
{
private:
  constexpr derived& Derived() noexcept { return static_cast<derived&>(*this); }

  constexpr const derived& Derived() const noexcept { return static_cast<const derived&>(*this); }

protected:
  constexpr MultiDimArray() {}

public:
  // I've butchered the syntax in the following subscript operators, but I hope it captures what I intend to do.
  constexpr const T& operator()(HookTypeToPack<Derived().Dimensions, std::size_t> ...Is) const {
    return *(this->Derived()[ComputeIndex<Derived().Dimensions...>(Is...)]);
  }

  constexpr T& operator()(HookTypeToPack<Derived().Dimensions, std::size_t> ...Is) {
    return *(this->Derived()[ComputeIndex<Derived().Dimensions...>(Is...)]);
  }
};

/** Static Multi-dimensional Array Class */
template <class T, std::size_t ...Dims>
class StaticMultiDimArray : public std::array<T, (Dims * ...)>,
                            public MultiDimArray<StaticMultiDimArray<T, (Dims * ...)>, T>
{
private:
  constexpr static std::size_t nEntries = (Dims * ...);
  constexpr static std::tuple<HookTypeToPack<Dims, std::size_t>...> Dimensions = std::make_tuple(Dims...);
  friend MultiDimArray<StaticMultiDimArray<T, (Dims * ...)>, T>;

public:
  constexpr StaticMultiDimArray() : std::array<T, nEntries>(InitStaticArray<T, nEntries>(0.0)) {}
};

/** Dynamic Multi-dimensional Array Class */
template <class T>
class DynamicMultiDimArray : public std::vector<T>, public MultiDimArray<DynamicMultiDimArray<T>, T>
{
private:
  std::size_t nEntries;
  std::tuple<...> Dimensions; // Not sure what to use here considering a tuple is immutable
  friend MultiDimArray<DynamicMultiDimArray<T>, T>;

public:
  DynamicMultiDimArray() : std::vector<T>() {}

  template <typename ...Dims>
  DynamicMultiDimArray(Dims ...dimensions) : std::vector<T>((dimensions * ...), 0.0) { Resize(dimensions...); }

  template <typename ...Dims>
  void Resize(Dims ...dimensions)
  {
    nEntries = (dimensions * ...);
    this->resize(nEntries);
    // store dimensions in Dimensions...
  }
};
```

The support functions `InitStaticArray`, `HookTypeToPack`, and `ComputeIndex` used above are defined as follows:

```
template <class T, std::size_t size>
constexpr auto InitStaticArray(const T& value)
{
  std::array<T, size> arr;
  std::fill(arr.begin(), arr.end(), value);
  return arr;
}

template <std::size_t, typename T>
using HookTypeToPack = T;

template <std::size_t ...Dims>
constexpr std::size_t ComputeIndex(HookTypeToPack<Dims, std::size_t> ...multi_index)
{
  constexpr std::size_t dims_arr[] = {Dims...};
  std::size_t multi_index_arr[] = {multi_index...};

  std::size_t index(0), factor(1);
  for(int i = 0; i < sizeof...(Dims); i++)
  {
    assert(0 <= multi_index_arr[i] && multi_index_arr[i] < dims_arr[i]);
    index += factor * multi_index_arr[i];
    factor *= dims_arr[i];
  }

  assert(0 <= index && index < (Dims * ...));
  return index;
}
```

Can anyone give me some advice on how to store the array dimensions in `StaticMultiDimArray` and `DynamicMultiDimArray` so they can be appropriately invoked in the `operator()` overloads in `MultiDimArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options. One you are already hinting at: store the dimensions in the derived class. However, don't use a `std::tuple`; that allows every element to have a different type, while we just want the size of every dimension to be a `std::size_t`. Use a `std::array` for the static array, `std::vector` for the dynamic one:

```
template <class T, std::size_t ...Dims>
class StaticMultiDimArray :
    public std::array<T, ...>,
    public MultiDimArray<...>
{
  constexpr static std::array dimensions{Dims...};
  ...
};

template <class T>
class DynamicMultiDimArray :
    public std::vector<T>,
    public MultiDimArray<...>
{
  std::vector<std::size_t> dimensions;
  ...
};
```

You also don't need to make the constructor of `DynamicMultiDimArray` a template, instead you can have it take a [`std:initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) as an argument, like so:

```
DynamicMultiDimArray(std::initializer_list<std::size_t> dimensions) :
    std::vector<T>(std::accumulate(dimensions.begin(), dimensions.end(), std::size_t{1}, std::multiplies<std::size_t>())),
    Dimensions(dimensions) {}
```

Yeah, the initialization of the actual vector of elements looks very ugly now. I would recommend not using inheritance for this, but composition. Then you can initialize the dimensions first, then the array/vector of data, and can make a member variable in `MultiDimArray` that calculates the number of entries:

```
template <class derived, class T>
class MultiDimArray {
  ...
  constexpr std::size_t nEntries() const {
    const auto &dimensions = Derived().dimensions;
    return std::accumulate(dimensions.begin(), dimensions.end(), std::size_t{1}, std::multiplies<std::size_t>());
  }
  ...
};

template <class T>
class DynamicMultiDimArray :
    public MultiDimArray<...>
{
  std::vector<std::size_t> dimensions;
  std::vector<T> data;
  ...
public:
  DynamicMultiDimArray(std::initializer_list<std::size_t> dimensions) :
      Dimensions(dimensions),
      data(nEntries()) {}
};
```

Similarly, you can make `operator()` take a `std::initializer_list<std::size_t>` for the indices. Code using this looks like so:

```
DynamicMultiDimArray dimarr({3, 5, 7}); // create new array
...
std::cout << dimarr({1, 2, 3}) << '\n'; // print element at index 1, 2, 3
```

This avoids a lot of template hassle. You could even consider creating a custom multi-dimensional index type instead of a `std::initializer_list<std::size_t>`, making it easier to store indices in a variable and pass them around.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these solutions and ideas! Would you mind elaborating on why you say "the initialization of the actual vector of elements looks very ugly now"? Is it not just a matter of using `std::copy` to copy over the entries in the initialiser list into the `Dimensions` vector? Also, the reason I used templates was to avoid having to use curly braces in addition to the round braces. I suppose there's no way to get around that when using `initializer_list`s?

Comment: I meant initializing the array holding the data itself, not the `Dimensions`. Having to write `std::vector<T>(std::accumulate(...))` is a bit tedious and it's also hard to read. As for the templates, you can of course keep using that. However, using `std::initializer_list` or a custom type allows you to pass the dimensions or indices as a single variable. In fact, this will also allow you to overload `operator[]` to take multi-dimensional indices! Of course, if you want to avoid the braces then you will need variadic templates. But use `template<size_t ...Dims>` then.